# Greevil consumable items: usage and meaning?

Tags: dota-2

What is the *Greevil* items used for?

I'm talking about current *Greevil* common consumable items:

- Kindler's Kit
- Pile of Coil
- Fistful of Snowballs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greevil common consumable items are nothing more than garbage at the present moment.

- Kindler's Kit
- Pile of Coil
- Fistful of Snowballs

Maybe one day will be worth something, but not right now.